# Combine IF & AND Formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following formulas

1. `=IF(AND(C2>35;V2<15%;AA53="");"Groothandel";"")`
2. `=IF(AND(C2>35;V2>15%;W2>15%);"Dropshipper";"")`
3. `=IF(AND(W2<15%;AA50="");"Private Label";"")`
4. `=IF(AND(W2>15%;AA51="");"White Label";"")`

I need to combine those into 1 big formula.

Essentially these formulas are here to find out which type of store this is.

I think there also might be an easier way to find out which kind of store it is.

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HNTdFvN_GW59ojrSgXXZdxgiIj7KBg_eHqkhO_K-QNU/edit#gid=0

Comment: The link to your file is not public. Make sure your sharing settings are set so that anyone with the link can view your sheet

Comment: Always try to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF(AND(C2>35; V2<15%; AA53=""); "Groothandel";
 IF(AND(C2>35; V2>15%; W2>15%); "Dropshipper";
 IF(AND(W2<15%; AA50=""); "Private Label";
 IF(AND(W2>15%; AA51=""); "White Label"; ))))
```

Comment: Thank you player0 and sorry for not sharing the file, which I did now.

Though this formula is correct, it needs to take into account that 

IF(AND(C2>35; V2<15%; AA53=""); "Groothandel";
 IF(AND(C2>35; V2>15%; W2>15%); "Dropshipper";

Are more important than 

 IF(AND(W2<15%; AA50=""); "Private Label";
 IF(AND(W2>15%; AA51=""); "White Label"; )

This because the Groothandel & Dropshipper have more requirements then the other 2. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: @Bolmotion see D2 in your sheet